# How to post a new answer to a question with Google My business API in PHP

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

We have a Google My business account that manage multiple locations. I want to create an interface for answering questions. My problem is that I can't find how to retreive the Author object for the current location.

I tried creating a new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Author object and submitting it but it doesn't seems to work. I'm using MyBusiness API 4.5

```
$author = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Author();
$author->setDisplayName('location display name');
$author->setProfilePhotoUrl('someurl.jpg');
$author->setType('MERCHANT');

$answer = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Answer();
$answer->setText($_POST['answerReplyText']);
$answer->setAuthor($author);

$postBody = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_UpsertAnswerRequest();
$postBody->setAnswer($answer);

try {
    $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_questions_answers->upsert($_POST['question_name'],$postBody);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I get the 'Request contains an invalid argument' exception. I am doing this the right way ? What should I do to make my answer valid ?

Comment: I just ran in exactly the same problem, this used to work, but now I only get the "invalid argument"-exceptions.

Comment: btw the "author"-field of the answer is "output-only" so there is no need to set it.

Comment: I just received an answer from the gmb api support, they are currently investigating a problem in the api. I reported this issue to them, since the api request doesn't only fail via the php-sdk but also via their own oauth2 playground.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following by removing the output only fields:

```
// $author = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Author();
// $author->setDisplayName('location display name');
// $author->setProfilePhotoUrl('someurl.jpg');
// $author->setType('MERCHANT');

$answer = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_Answer();
$answer->setText($_POST['answerReplyText']);
// $answer->setAuthor($author);

$postBody = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_UpsertAnswerRequest();
$postBody->setAnswer($answer);

try {
    $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_questions_answers->upsert($_POST['question_name'],$postBody);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

This works for me quite well. Hope this will help you too.